# Should I include Ivdd for total current consumption calculation?

Tags: microcontroller, current, power-consumption

I'm looking at the [STM8L101K3T6](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/cd00220591-1796992.pdf) microcontroller for a timer and would like to calculate the average current consumption. It will stay active for only 5% of the time while it sleeps for the other 95% of time. I would also like 1 Mhz speed and the average current consumption must be well below 400 μA.

On the datasheet, under total current characteristics (pg 39) it says Ivdd consumes 80 mA. And then I look under total current consumption in Run mode (pg-42), and it says Idd, it says current consumption is 0.7 mA at f = 2 Mhz. So when I'm doing the active mode calculation for current, do I add Ivdd (80 mA) and Idd (0.7 mA)?

I'm new to microcontrollers for sorry if this is a simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

The IVDD found in table 14 is "Absolute maximum ratings", it is the most current the device can draw before something breaks. The way to reach this maxima is by pulling current on many outputs at once, i.e. one cannot pull the specified max 25mA from more than a few outputs at once.

In order to calculate typical power consumption, you shall look at Table 18. Then of course to the numbers there you must add the consumption of any loads connected to outputs etc.

Comment: Thank you for your input! So if I would like the average current consumption of the microcontroller, and the device is active for 5% of the time, would I take 0.7mA from table 18 for active and 1.2uA from table 20 for sleep mode and do the calculation below?

Comment: 0.7mA*0.05 + 1.2uA*0.95

Comment: @RemaFiroz Yes, that would be a decent approximation.